# Trouble viewing cart items from admin page on django site

Tags: python, django, cart

Here is my views.py

````
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cart


def cart(request):
 Cart = Cart.objects.get(id=1)

 context = {
     'items': Product.objects.all(),
     'object': obj,
     'id': obj.id, 
     'name': obj.name,
     'cover': obj.image,
     'author': obj.author,
    
 }
 
 return render(request,'bookstore/cart.html', context)
 
 ```



Here is my models.py
````

````
from django.db import models
from apps.bookstore.models import Product

class Cart(models.Model):

products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,blank=True)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65, decimal_places=2,default=0.00)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "Cart id: %s" %(self.id)   
```
````

Here is my cart.html

```
 {%  extends 'bookstore/main.html' %}
 {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
 from .models import Product
 from cart.models import Cart

 {% block content %}
 <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>

 <table>

   {% for item in items %}
     <tr>          
     {{ item.name }} 
     <td>{{ item.author }}</td> 
    </tr>  
   {% endfor %}



 {% endblock content %}
```

It seems like something is wrong with my models.py portion. In my admin page I can add the items I have from the bookstore to the cart however when I go to look at them on the website nothing is displayed.

Comment: Be sure you register your model with admin

Comment: I did, I am able to see the cart object in admin too